# Wagtail - how to make user management work with User.is_active being a @property?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Making the `User.is_active` flag a python `@property` instead of a read database field results in the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (is_active) specified for User
```

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return ....
```

This is because `wagtail.users.forms.UserEditForm` included `"is_active"` in the fields:

```py
class UserEditForm(UserForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {User.USERNAME_FIELD, "is_active"} | standard_fields | custom_fields
```

This error occurs as long `"wagtail.users"` is included in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`, even when overriding the default forms as described in the [documentation](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/custom_user_models.html).

```py
WAGTAIL_USER_EDIT_FORM = 'users.forms.CustomUserEditForm'
WAGTAIL_USER_CREATION_FORM = 'users.forms.CustomUserCreationForm'
```

I tried to disable the wagtail user management entirely, but this does not seem to be possible.
https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/3657

Any ideas how to make this work?